# Issue in importing Tensorflow Probability

Tags: tensorflow, virtualenv, conda, importerror, tensorflow-probability

I have created a tensorflow tf in an virtual environment and not facing any issue in importing tensorflow. But I am unable to figure out the problem in importing tensorflow probability.

Tensorflow version is 2.3.0.

Saw similar issues in github etc but there was no helpful answer and could not solve the issue as of now.

Please help in sorting out the issue.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have a quite old version of TFP. Can you run `pip freeze` to see what is installed? The TFP version compatible with TF 2.3 is TFP 0.11 (latest are TF 2.4, TFP 0.12).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the version part of tfp. Actually, I had a mismatch b/w tensorflow and tfp versions. I solved the issue by creating a new virtual environment and installing tensorflow version 2.1.0 and tfp version 0.9.0. It solved the bug.